# Mathematica is unable to compute the derivative of the function $\frac{\sin^2(x)}x$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, discontinuity

Consider the function
$$f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto\begin{cases}\frac{\sin^2(x)}x, & x\neq 0, \\ 0, & x=0.\end{cases}$$

It is true that $f\in\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ and that
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{2 \sin (x) \cos (x)}{x}-\frac{\sin ^2(x)}{x^2}, & x\neq 0, \\ 1, & x=0.\end{cases}$$

(The fact that $f'(0)=1$ can be derived directly from the definition of the derivative.)

However, when I enter $f'(0)$ [into Mathematica](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5BPiecewise%5B%7B%7BSin%5Bx%5D%5E2%2Fx%2Cx%21%3D0%7D%2C%7B0%2Cx%3D%3D0%7D%7D%5D%2Cx%5D+where+x%3D0) (in this case Wolfram Alpha but it makes no difference), I get $f'(0)=0$. Even more astonishingly, if I define $$g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto\begin{cases} \frac{\sin^2(x)}x, & x\neq0, \\ x, & x=0,\end{cases}$$

then $f=g$. However, [Mathematica gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5BPiecewise%5B%7B%7BSin%5Bx%5D%5E2%2Fx%2Cx%21%3D0%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cx%3D%3D0%7D%7D%5D%2Cx%5D+where+x%3D0) $g'(0)=1\color{red}\neq f'(0)$. It seems that Mathematica has a massive programming error when it comes to differentiating piecewise functions!

Is this a known error?

---

Note: This bug was originally discovered by Micah Windsor in a discussion on $f'(0)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619260/).

Comment: if you do `Limit[D[f[x], x], x -> 0]` it gives `1` I do not know why it does not work on the Piecewise function itself.

Comment: `SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]` works (12.1.0), but `SeriesCoefficient[f[$x], {$x, x, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]` gives a rather interesting answer.

Comment: It's not a bug (or an error). Substituting 0 for `x` in the derivative gives an indeterminate form that happens to be at a removable singularity. `Series` can be quite useful in such cases (and so can `Limit`, but that's a heavier hammer).

Comment: This is a task usually given in the introductory course of mathematical analysis. It is for proving considerations an example working for small values around a point, x=0. The students are requested to make use of the Taylor expansion Series and an idea of limit introduced in the lessons. It is not an example of Piesewise or D or f'. It is an easy hand or head task. The function is not in need for Piecewise at all. Taylor series multiplication may be another context.

Comment: `Limit[D[Sinc[x] Sin[x], x], x -> 0]` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See the possible issues section of the documentation for [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html). The proper method for defining `f` is

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sin[x]^2/x, x < 0 || x > 0}}]

f[0]

(* 0 *)

f'[0]

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Side note: in _v9.0.1_ `f'[x]` still gives the undesired result `Piecewise[{{(2*Cos[x]*Sin[x])/x - Sin[x]^2/x^2, x > 0 || x < 0}}, 0]`, but `D[f[x], x]` gives the desired `Piecewise[{{(2*Cos[x]*Sin[x])/x - Sin[x]^2/x^2, x < 0}, {1, x == 0}}, 
   (2*Cos[x]*Sin[x])/x - Sin[x]^2/x^2]`, seems like a bug in _v9_.